# Comparator with two noninverting inputs?

Tags: comparator

On page 7 of the [LTC3631 datasheet](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/3631fe.pdf), the diagram shows a comparator with two noninverting inputs. What does such a comparator do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this context, it means that the comparator can be triggered by comparison of the inverting input against both of the two non-inverting inputs. My impression (though I'm not 100% certain on this) is that the inverting input needs to exceed *both* of the non-inverting inputs to switch the output. The input hooked to the soft-start pin is dominant at start up, but during normal operation, the 800 mV reference is dominant. This means that at start-up, the inductor current cycles more slowly than during normal operation.

Here's the description from the datasheet of the what the comparator does during normal operation:

> The inductor current 
>   increases until either the current exceeds the peak current 
>   comparator threshold or the voltage on the VFB pin 
>   exceeds 800mV, at which time the high side power switch 
>   is turned off, and the low side power switch (N-channel 
>   MOSFET) turns on. The inductor current ramps down until 
>   the reverse current comparator trips, signaling that the 
>   current is close to zero. If the voltage on the VFB pin is 
>   still less than the 800mV reference, the high side power 
>   switch is turned on again and another cycle commences.